# BluetoothLeAdvertiser - DeadObjectException

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon-android, gatt

I have been working on an Android application to emit Eddystone beacons.
I am using an IntentService to start advertising beacons. Intent Service stops after calling the startAdvertising function but I set an alarm which triggers every X minutes. So after X minutes, I call stopAdvertising and then startAdvertising again. I set the AdvertiseCallback to be static and hence I have the same clientIf = 5 everytime. This works properly but like after every X*23 minutes approximately, I get DeadObjectException.

```
1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/AlarmReceiver: Alarm triggered
07-27 18:02:12.017 1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/BeaconEmitter: Data prepared to be advertised : Prefix - 007B Device token - 79b83b18f551c2aa Time token - 95feed22db47
07-27 18:02:12.110 1950-1966/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
07-27 18:10:48.195 1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/AlarmReceiver: Alarm triggered
07-27 18:10:48.207 1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/BeaconEmitter: Data prepared to be advertised : Prefix - 007B Device token - 79b83b18f551c2aa Time token - b8b23f4ef347
07-27 18:10:48.276 1950-21988/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
07-27 18:10:50.287 1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground E/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: remote exception when unregistering
                                                                                                              android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                                                                  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                                  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                                                                                                                  at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.unregisterClient(IBluetoothGatt.java:866)
                                                                                                                  at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeAdvertiser$AdvertiseCallbackWrapper.startRegisteration(BluetoothLeAdvertiser.java:278)
                                                                                                                  at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(BluetoothLeAdvertiser.java:141)
                                                                                                                  at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(BluetoothLeAdvertiser.java:90)
                                                                                                                  at com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground.BeaconEmitter.rotateBeaconID(BeaconEmitter.java:309)
                                                                                                                  at com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:32)
                                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2662)
                                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:160)
                                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
                                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:984)
                                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-27 18:10:50.542 1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground W/BluetoothReceiver: Bluetooth is OFF. Stop emitting beacon service. Also stopping the scheduled alarm
07-27 18:10:54.114 1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground W/BluetoothReceiver: Bluetooth is OFF. Stop emitting beacon service. Also stopping the scheduled alarm
07-27 18:10:58.712 1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/BluetoothReceiver: Bluetooth ON. Checking for compatibility
07-27 18:10:58.717 1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/BluetoothReceiver: Bluetooth ON and compatible. Start emitting beacon service. Also scheduling alarm
07-27 18:10:58.763 1950-4939/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/BeaconEmitter: Data prepared to be advertised : Prefix - 007B Device token - 79b83b18f551c2aa Time token - b8b23f4ef347
07-27 18:10:58.775 1950-21988/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
07-27 18:17:35.334 1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/AlarmReceiver: Alarm triggered
07-27 18:17:35.343 1950-1950/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/BeaconEmitter: Data prepared to be advertised : Prefix - 007B Device token - 79b83b18f551c2aa Time token - e2697456de83
07-27 18:17:35.391 1950-11251/com.ppp.beaconbroadcasterservice.beaconemitterbackground D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
```

So this exception doesn't affect advertising, but it seems that it switches off the Bluetooth and then switches ON again.
This happens almost every X*23 minutes approximately. I crosschecked with values of X = 1 minute and 5 minutes.

Any reason for this? How to avoid this exception?

Part of the code which is repeated every 5 minutes with the help of alarm manager.

```
 /**
 * The rotation part which will be executed every 5 minutes
 */
public void rotateBeaconID()
{
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

    //Change the advertise data to reflect the new timetoken in the beacon packet
    mAdvertiseData = setAdvertiseData();
    //Change the advertising settings
    mAdvertiseSettings = setAdvertiseSettings();
    //Stop the current advertisement
    mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(mAdvertiseCallback);
    //Start advertising again with the new beacon packet
    mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(mAdvertiseSettings, mAdvertiseData, mAdvertiseCallback);
    //Write the logs to a file in the device
    LogRotate.writeLogToFile();
}
```

This function is a method of IntentService class.
Thanks

Comment: This may be something to do with the internals of the Bluetooth stack on your device.   I suspect this is not documented behavior or a programming error on your part.  This is a fancy way of saying it may be an Android bug.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it looks like your IntentService is initiating all the components that are required to startAdvertising. Those objects are stored in memory and belong to the IntentService that is destroyed once the Advertisement method completes (An IntentService is used to perform a short task and self destructד upon finishing).

After x minutes, the alarm wakes up and tries to stop the advertisements by using the resources that the IntentService initiated... but now you have a problem:

The Intent service no longer exists because it was destroyed together with all its resources, so the alarm initiated task is trying to invoke a DeadObject hence the DeadObjectException.

Comment: This process of stopAdvertising and startAdvertising every X minutes works for like a long time. If X is 5 minutes, stopAdvertising and startAdvertising was called every 5 minutes for like 2 hours and then DeadObjectException. After the exception, nothing stopped, rotation part was working again. IntentService stops after the first startAdvertising call. 2 hours is much more than the IntentService running time. So, Dead Object Exception is Bluetooth related rather than the IntentService I feel.